# isolate an ng-click inside of an ng-repeat loop to the element clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I apologize for the badly worded question, I am new to Angularjs. Working with ng-repeat and an ng-click that requests additional information from the controller.  When performing the ng-click, all users are updated because they belong to the ng-repeat.

Is it possible to isolate the ng-click or set up the template so only the active user receives the data requested?

I tried some conditional logic with the results tag and the ng-click in the controller but was unsuccessful. Thanks!

jsfiddle here with example code: http://jsfiddle.net/2cd3tr55/2/

::HTML::

```
<div ng-controller="DomReadyCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{test}}</p>
    <div class="loop" ng-repeat='user in users track by $index'>
        <div id="{{user.name}}">
            <strong>user: </strong><em>{{user.name}} {{user.name == 'bert' ? '--toggle on bert' : ''}}</em>
            <div>
                <a ng-class="user{{user.id}}" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="GetUsername(user.id)">Get More Info:</a>
                <br>
                <span class="stats"> Months Worked: {{stats[0].months_worked}}, PTO Earned: {{stats[0].pto_earned}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

::JS::

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('DomReadyCtrl', function($timeout, $scope){
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.test = "World";
    $scope.users = [ 
        {'name':'al','id':'0'},
        {'name':'bert','id':'1'},
        {'name':'charles','id':'2'},
        {'name':'dave','id':'3'},
        {'name':'eddie','id':'4'},
        {'name':'frank','id':'5'}
        ];
    //console.log($scope.users);

    document.body.setAttribute('class', 'red');
    alert('Angular view not ready');

    $scope.GetUsername = function(userID) { // ng-click gets new array data
        $scope.stats = [];
        if ( userID == '0' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '30', 'pto_earned': '0'}              
           ]
            // console.log($scope.stats);
        }
        if ( userID == '1' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '31', 'pto_earned': '1'}              
           ]
        }
        if ( userID == '2' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '32', 'pto_earned': '2'}              
           ]
        }
        if ( userID == '3' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '33', 'pto_earned': '3'}              
           ]
        }
        if ( userID == '4' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '34', 'pto_earned': '4'}              
           ]
        }
        if ( userID == '5' ) {
          $scope.stats = [
              {'months_worked' : '35', 'pto_earned': '5'}              
           ]
        }
    }

});
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);

document.body.setAttribute('class', 'green');

$("#bert em").on('click',function() { //click on bert
    $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    $(this).children('div').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with `ng-click()`. Instead, it appears to me the likely problem is that you only have one stats element used by all of the users' divs.

In your HTML you probably want to replace this:

```
<span class="stats"> Months Worked: {{stats[0].months_worked}}, PTO Earned: {{stats[0].pto_earned}}</span>
```

With something like this:

```
<span class="stats"> Months Worked: {{stats[$index].months_worked}}, PTO Earned: {{stats[$index].pto_earned}}</span>
```

And in your Javascript, for each userId case, you probably want something more like this:

```
$scope.stats[userId] = {'months_worked' : '30', 'pto_earned': '0'}
```

Or alternately, include the stats within the user object itself and pass the user object itself into the ng-click handler.

Comment: Your advice was very helpful and works great! I had a typo on the userID during my first test (should be userID).  Works exactly as I hoped - http://jsfiddle.net/2cd3tr55/5/  Thank You!!